# Discarding Destination Tickets in Ticket to Ride

Tags: ticket-to-ride

When you choose 3 destination tickets on your turn, what is the rule in regards to if you need to keep 1, 2, or 3? It seems that you must decide before your next turn.

Toward the end of the game, players may want to discard destination tickets. is this allowed?

Anyone has any copy of the rules or rules on hand to clarify this?

Answer (score 18):

You may keep 1, 2, or all 3 destination tickets.

You must make your decision before the beginning of the next players turn (not before your next turn as you stated).

The only two ways you may discard destination tickets are during your beginning of game ticket selection (you must keep at least two) and when using the Draw 3 Tickets as your action for the turn (you must keep at least one). For Draw 3 Tickets, you can only discard the tickets you drew this turn.

The rules can be found on the [Days of Wonder](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/7201-T2R-Rules-EN-2019.pdf) website.

> each player taking one turn at a time

Comment: While User 1873 has correctly stated the official rule, in casual play, it's extremely common for players to ask for your permission to play before you've discarded. You should give this, unhesitatingly... seeing their play is usually to your advantage. If someone asks another player, you should discourage it. Not so much because it's against the rules, but because it's to the drawing person's benefit.

Comment: When playing with my family, we usually let the flow of the game continue, unless someone wants to make a route. Since the route could change the decision of the destination ticket, we forbid it. But taking trains or even asking for dest. tickets is allowed, since there is no change in the decision (at least we don't see any).

Comment: @gbianchi - If there were fewer than 3 destination tickets left in the stack, then the tickets returned by the current player could, of course, affect the decision of the player attempting to draw destination tickets - and the order in which the current player returns them to the bottom. This is, admittedly, quite rare.

Comment: Your link to the rules is broken. Try this: http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/usa/rules/.